# Sinatra: pass nested routes to controllers

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What I try to achieve with Sinatra is, I think fairly simple issue. I have a bunch of controllers (coming from the Rails world) and I run them from my *config.ru*, which looks like:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require './app'

# require all the parts needed
Dir.glob('./{controllers,helpers,models}/*.rb').each { |file| require file }

# start the server via Rack map method which binds route to Sinatra app
map('/') { run ApplicationController }
map('/') { run AuthenticationController }
map('/customers') { run CustomerController }
map('/contact_us') { run ContactUsController }
```

They're subclasses of ApplicationController (itself subclass of App < Sinatra::Base) and then I'm doing something like this inside

```
  get '/:id/home' do
    erb :'/customers/home'
  end
```

What I want to do is to be able to use nested routes with id like */customers/:id/contacts* without duplicating whole path in controller. I cannot do this with map and using *namespace* also doesn't seem like a way how to solve this. I'm open to suggestions how to structure it better to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do this instead (note: You should be `use`ing each extra controller instead of running them.

```
run ApplicationController
use AuthenticationController
use CustomerController
use ContactUsController
```

Then in each controller you would need to inherit the ApplicationController class like so:

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
    get "/" do
        erb :index
    end
end
```

#### Bonus:

You could even add this to your `config.ru` to avoid having to type `use` for all those controllers:

```
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "app/controllers", "*.rb")].collect {|file| File.basename(file).split(".")[0] }.reject {|file| file == "application_controller" }.each do |file|
  string_class_name = file.split('_').collect { |w| w.capitalize }.join
  class_name = Object.const_get(string_class_name)
  use class_name
end
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting, that means if I'am not mistaken using them as middleware. I need to read up on it.